# Suddenly unable to SSh and FTP into my Linux VPS

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, vps, timeout

I am having a very strange problem whereas I am suddenly unable to login to my VPS via SSH and FTP.

I have accessed the VPS through a control panel and restarted it. I have also checked that the ssh service is running and it's working fine.

I have checked SSH process on the local machine as well and it seems all fine too. It claims it is running.

The problem I am having is that when I try and run the command:

```
ssh root@*******.io
```

the terminal hangs and times out. This has never happened before and is also happening when I attempt to FTP in. One thing I did do earlier that may have something to do with it is run a:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

on the local machine. I would assume this wouldn't uninstall anything that would be needed by the machine?

I am at a loss here and not sure where I start start to diagnose this problem so any help is appreciated. It has only started having this problem today and has never had it before.

Thanks

Comment: Can you ping the server? Can the server ping the internet?

Comment: why don't you ask your provider to look into it? any recent changes were done? firewall for instance..

Comment: Since the only thing you think might be related is on the local machine, you should test the connection on another machine.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons to block FTP and SSH
1) If your system is full. Means there is no space and other thing CPU utilisation or RAM is complete used so you cannot ssh or FTP.

2) Check Firewall rules

3) check if IP is pinged and hostname is not? It means problem is with DNS assigning provision. Check /etc/resolve.conf for that.

4) Perhaps this one is not good solution but you can try to restart system. ( Sometimes it works)

Thanks HTH

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your IP address is blocked on the server?

Try to login from another ISP provider  and check the IP address block.

To view the blocked IP address please run the following command

iptables -L INPUT -v -n | less

Answer (score 0):

If you recently updated, newer OpenSSH in most distros have the login with a password option disabled.  Also just prior to that, most of them deprecated DSS keys, so if you are using an old style key (not keyboard) to login either re-enable the DSS keys (in both client and server) or regenerate a new RSA key.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test with another account ? Maybe, you are not permitted anymore to login through SSH with root.

Do you have access to a console in your VPS panel ? If so, try to look at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and check the line `PermitRootLogin`.

Answer (score -1):

So, this issue has been resolved and it was nothing to do with either the VPS or my local machine.

At my work we have two gateways that allow requests in and out of the network. Yesterday, we had some internet issues and the default gateway was switched. This gateway had differing rules (stupidly) than the default one and was causing the problems that were occurring with my SSH and FTP requests.

To solve this, I changed the default gateway IP address on my local Linux machine to the original one and voila, I am able to make requests again.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: This simply shows that you were lacking real basic troubleshooting when you posted the question as every single word in it was misleading as I suspected.

Comment: Thanks for you completely pointless comment. You're an asshole.

Comment: My comment was very justified considering that your question included nothing about your network configuration although it was apparently at fault, and when asked questions in the comments, you responded to no one who tried to help you.  Keep your insults to yourself, you deserve them.

Comment: Your comment wasn't justified at all. I am relatively new to this sort of thing and explained it to the best of my knowledge and ability. I left work shortly after posting this question and by the time I came back the next day the problem had been solved. Why would I comment on responses when I already had the answer? I thanked everyone for their help in my final answer too so I was giving acknowledgement. This site is about helping others, not trying to belittle those who may not be of the same skill as you. Take your condescending words elsewhere.